# adding to mule payload

Tags: mule, addition, esb, mule-studio

I need to add a number to one of the payload parameters. If the payload.zone parameter is 45 and embed this #[payload.zone + 1] I get 451. Rather I want the result to be 46. What expression will allow that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see zone is a String object. For that reason, you are getting 451. To get the expected value you can convert to integer

```
#[Integer.parseInt(payload.zone) + 1]
```